# How can I access a variable inside a nested array?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to access a variable in a nested array, but I keep getting an error saying "list index out of range". I'm using something like this:

`userlist = [['Number', 'Name', 'Password', 'Balance'], ['1', 'Bob', '12345', '2.34'], ['2', 'Jake', '0000', '2.64']]`

I'm trying to print the first term of every array in userlist, so I used this:

```
for dataset in userlist:
    print (dataset[0])
```

I expected the output to be

```
Number
1
2
```

But instead I get an error. Could someone please help?

Thanks,

Comment: Your code is OK

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I got the arrays from a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an empty list lurking inside `userlist`.

Try

```
userlist = [[], ['Number', 'Name', 'Password', 'Balance'], ['1', 'Bob', '12345', '2.34'], ['2', 'Jake', '0000', '2.64']]
for dataset in userlist:
    print(dataset[0])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/wil/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/zrxtz.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(dataset[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

To fix the problem, use a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) of `None` to filter out the empty lists:

```
userlist = [[], ['Number', 'Name', 'Password', 'Balance'], ['1', 'Bob', '12345', '2.34'], ['2', 'Jake', '0000', '2.64']]
userlist = filter(None, userlist)
for dataset in userlist:
    print(dataset[0])
```

Output:

```
Number
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(userlist)):
    if(len(userlist[i])>0):
       print(userlist[i][0])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sadly, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Gianmarco It does *attempt* to answer the question. It might be wrong or not detailed enough, but that isn't a reason to delete it. If you don't like it, you can downvote it, but deletion is only for stuff that doesn't even attempt to answer the question like "thanks" or "I'm having this problem too". See [this post by a moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/4284627).